# Showing that $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, exponential-function

> Let $f(x)=e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

**My attempt:**

Note that $f^{(n)}(x)=e^x$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$. In particular, $f^{(n)}(0)=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$.

Now, $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}+e^\zeta\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$ for some $\zeta$ between $0$ and $x$.

Let $M>0.$ Take $x\in[-M,M]$. Then $$\left| e^\zeta\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\right |\leq e^M\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\leq e^M\frac{M^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

Since the RHS$\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, then the LHS$\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

We conclude that for all $x\in[-M,M]$ we have $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$ Since $M$ is arbitrary, the equality holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is this solution correct?

**Addendum:**
The definition of $e^x$ I'm using is $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$

Comment: What is your definition of $e^x$? If you are defining it as the solution of $y'=y, y(0)=1$, then you know $f^{(n)}(0)=1$ for all $n=0,1,2,\dots$ and you can use Taylor coefficients.

Comment: We all know what $e$ is, but as noted above you need to give a definition.

Comment: My definition of $e^x$ is $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right )^n$

Comment: How are you calculating derivatives of $e^x$ with that definition. Note that we can't commute the limit and the derivative because that requires us to know that the limit is differentiable, which is partially assuming the conclusion.

Comment: Another approach is to use the obvious inequalities $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n} \right) ^n\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^k}{k!}\leq\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n} $$ for all positive $x$ and all integers $n>x$. For negative $x$ you can note that both $e^x$ (your definition) and the power series satisfy the functional equation $f(x+y) =f(x) f(y) $.